# Which Carbocation is most stable among the three?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, resonance, carbocation, inductive-effect

[image]

According to me the answer should be (C)  as that Carbocation will be stablized by resonance with Chlorine.
I have read that resonance is the biggest deciding factor about the stability of a carbocation 
But some argue that (A) would be most stable as it is farthest away from a highly electronegative Chlorine atom.
Please help

Comment: Are you sure B can be discharged out discussion?

Comment: i do not agree with you because Cl is considered a deactivating(electron withdrawing) groupand the carbon will be very posistive which this itself causes instablitiy.

Comment: If you're not "supposed to" think about chloronium in such case then such question is pretty much waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct as resonance is most powerful factor for stabilisation of carbonation So C is most stable and after that due to hyperconjugation B would be more stable than A. Order for governing stability is

$\text{resonance}>\text{hyperconjugation}>\text{inductive}$

Comment: What about overlap strength? I mean, I know that for fluorine, overlap of lone pairs from 2p of fluorine to empty p of carbocation is quite stabilising. Can the same be said for overlap of empty p of C and 3p of Cl?